# Validating MAC addresses

Tags: c

I have a question about validation of MAC address:

These MAC addresses are valid:

```
00:0A:02:0B:03:0C
ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

These addresses, however, are not valid:

```
00:0A:02:0k:03:0j
00:0A:02_00:03?0C
```

How is it possible to check the validity of a MAC address using C?

Comment: A loop, checking with [`isxdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isxdigit), and comparing against `':'` in the right places? And of course start with the length, if the length is incorrect no need to check any more.

Comment: What platform do you need to do this on?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. It seems you want us to write some code for you. While many of us here will be happy to help a programmer in distress, it is advisable to post code, and show that you invested some effort into solving your problem.

Comment: You could go for a regular expression, but that's not vanilla C, you'll need a library to do this, which will depend on your platform a little. Most have posix reg exps though.

Answer (score 3):

Simple loop which checks if each character is appropriate for its position should be enough:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool isMAC(char *s) {
    for(i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
        if(i % 3 != 2 && !isxdigit(s[i]))
            return false;
        if(i % 3 == 2 && s[i] != ':')
            return false;
    }
    if(s[17] != '\0')
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want the weight of using a regex library<sup>1</sup>, just build a simple FSM that checks for two hex digits (use [`isxdigit`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isxdigit.htm) or a simple lookup in `0123456789abcdefABCDEF`) followed by a `:` (or `-`) repeated six times (except for the last group) or four hex digits followed by a `.` repeated three times (except for the last group).

Try writing the code yourself. And if you have trouble, post a new *very specific* question with your code and the issue that you're having.

1: For this, you don't.

Comment: If he's having trouble with this, I don't think writing a state machine is within his current skill set.